# Changing and setting button background color and also comparing clicks on button pressed using switch and case

Tags: android, button, switch-statement

I have been working on an examination app for a while now,
Please am stock with setting buttons background colors as well comparing values on every button pressed.
Below is my code, please where am I getting it wrong?
It gives me no error and don't satisfy the desired task.

```
    switch (V.getId()) {
    case R.id.option1:
        Button s2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.option2);
        actual = bOption1.getText().toString();
        s2.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF33FF33, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        bOption2.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x33FF33FF, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        bOption3.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x33FF33FF, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        bOption4.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x33FF33FF, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        aoption1 = 1;
        aoption2 = 0;
        aoption3 = 0;
        aoption4 = 0;
        break;
    case R.id.option2:
        actual = bOption2.getText().toString();
        bOption1.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x33FF33FF, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        bOption2.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF33FF33, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        bOption3.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x33FF33FF, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        bOption4.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x33FF33FF, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        aoption1 = 0;
        aoption2 = 1;
        aoption3 = 0;
        aoption4 = 0;
        break;
    case R.id.option3:
        actual = bOption3.getText().toString();
        bOption1.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x33FF33FF, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        bOption2.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x33FF33FF, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        bOption3.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF33FF33, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        bOption4.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x33FF33FF, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        aoption1 = 0;
        aoption2 = 0;
        aoption3 = 1;
        aoption4 = 0;
        break;
    case R.id.option4:
        actual = bOption4.getText().toString();
        bOption1.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x33FF33FF, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        bOption2.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x33FF33FF, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        bOption3.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x33FF33FF, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        bOption4.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF33FF33, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        aoption1 = 0;
        aoption2 = 0;
        aoption3 = 0;
        aoption4 = 1;
        break;
    case R.id.confirm:
        tvexplain.setText(explain);
        ahint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        proceed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        proceed.setText(continued);
        confirm.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        confirm.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(3, 1));
        if(actual.equals(null)){ }else{
            if(actual.equals(answer)){
                if(aoption1 == 1){
                    bOption1.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF66FF66, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                }else if(aoption2 == 1){
                    bOption2.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF66FF66, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                }else if(aoption3 == 1){
                    bOption3.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF66FF66, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                }else if(aoption4 == 1){
                    bOption4.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF66FF66, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }
```

Comment: As long as your views `R.id.option*` are contained in the currently active layout your switch should work fine. You can set a breakpoint or a log call somewhere in your switch cases to make sure they are getting hit. For setting your background, try just doing something like `bOption2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33FF33FF"));`

Comment: Prefer an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) over a wall of code!

Comment: Sure, all buttons were initialised in my onCreate function and also when I tried setting button background color this way, it ends up destroying the look and feel of the button.
I will still try some other techniques and will update it here as well.
Thanks for the response all and more options will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [Android Art Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) to create different colors for your buttons?